# Distance between center to any point on edge of rectangle in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

[image]

As you can see in above picture, suppose that there is a ray emitted from center and collides at edge of rectangle. so I want to calculate at which point it collides, so that I could be able to calculate distance between point on edge and center.

- What we know?

  - width and height of rectangle
  - a degree & b degree (as shown in above figure)
  - centerX, centerY

Comment: I have a feeling that this is better off at Math.SE, without the JS part because that isn't quite relevant

Comment: @AndrewL.But i want to get answer in javascript function, as i am doing one javascript project that needs this calculation

Comment: The question is about a math calculation, thus it's more suited for Math.SE. It doesn't really matter if it's for a JS project, it's a question about math

Comment: @HiteshUpadhyay but first find the mathematic way to calculate it and then just apply it in javascript or any other language you want.

Comment: @AndrewL. hey bro, i understand your feeling, but it would be helpful if you help me to get answer of this question. if you have useful link then i would appreciate it.

Comment: @HiteshUpadhyay  I can't do that here because this is off-topic. Math.SE will probably yield better results. Once you've calculated it, then apply it to JS

Comment: @AndrewL.Hey brother, according to your suggestion, i have posted question to Math.SE. here is link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898206/distance-between-center-to-any-point-on-edge-of-rectangle-in-javascript

Comment: @HiteshUpadhyay Also note that the JavaScript part is COMPLETELY irrelevant on Math.SE. You can remove the words `in javascript` from its title.

Comment: @dorukayhan, thanks brother, just corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Let's center is (0, 0) and ray angle is `phi`. Pseudocode:

```
c = Cos(phi)
s = Sin(phi)
if Width * Abs(s) < Height * Abs(c) then
   x = Sign(c) * Width / 2
   y = Tan(phi) * x
else
   y = Sign(s) * Height / 2
   x = CoTan(phi) * y
```

Comment: Hello, may I ask what is Sign?

Comment: @lllllllllllll Function returns 1 for positive argument, 0 for zero, -1 for negative. `Math.sign()`  in JS

Comment: In Unity3D I had to swap cos/sin and tan/cot, but otherwise this worked great for me

Answer (score 0):

I found MBo's solution helpful for a game I'm working on in Unity3D. This is my adapted solution:

```
/// Returns the point on the edge of a rectangle in the given direction from the center
public static Vector2 PointOnRect(float radiusX, float radiusY, float radians)
{
  var normal = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(radians), Mathf.Cos(radians));
  if (Mathf.Abs(normal.x * radiusY) > Mathf.Abs(normal.y * radiusX))
  {
    // Left or right
    var x = Mathf.Sign(normal.x) * radiusX;
    var cot = normal.y / normal.x;
    return new Vector2(x, x * cot);
  }
  else
  {
    // Top or bottom
    var y = Mathf.Sign(normal.y) * radiusY;
    var tan = normal.x / normal.y;
    return new Vector2(y * tan, y);
  }
}
```