# Calculating dynamic length for an analog clock hand in relation to the bounding box

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

[Here is the illustration of the challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bqH4.png)

I need to create an analog clock where the length of one or more hands is dynamically adjusted to reach near the bounding box border. Starting point for the clock hands is not necessarily in the center of the bounding box.

I'd need to get the distance between the starting point and the end point - not just the x,y where the hand meets the bounding box border.

- Inside the bounding box top left is 0,0
- The box size can be for example 348x250
- Starting point for the clock hand can be either in the center x:174,
  y:125 (50%,50%) OR off center, something like x:214, y:90
- Because of the way the hands are implemented the actual length is
  needed - not just the x,y where the hand meets the edge

The best reference I found so far is this: [Distance between center to any point on edge of rectangle in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055985/distance-between-center-to-any-point-on-edge-of-rectangle-in-javascript)

Ideally I'd have a function something like this:

```
function getLength(angle) {// 0-360 degrees for rotating the hand with 0 in the top

    let boxWidth = 348;//top left is 0,0
    let boxHeight = 250;

    let clockX = 214;// center X for the 'clock'
    let clockY = 90;// center Y for the 'clock'

    // start the magic here
    let handlength;
    ....
    // end magic here

    return handLength //return the actual max length for the hand

}
```

No idea how to calculate it. Any help?

Comment: You can always just hide the overflow and have an white inset border to simulate the solution.

Comment: Hiding the overflow would be easy (it's for a smartwatch) - but I need the ends to be round so it can't be clipped by a mask or screen edge. Also rotating stuff way off screen may have some side effects on the platform.

Comment: If you really want to calculate it, you need a reference point. How is the point positioned relative to the bounding box? Can you assume that the top left is 0,0

Comment: I added some reference info to the original post. But yes - in the bounding box top left is 0,0 and the starting point for the hands can be something different than just in the middle of the box. @VincentChinner

Comment: Mainly Google :) I found an earlier post (stackoverflow.com/questions/39055985/…) asking for something a bit similar. But my math skills are nowhere near good enough to translate it into a working solution let alone make it so that the center point can be other than middle. @FrozenButcher

Comment: @Olian04 Thank you for the example. I actually did something similar first (there's actually just the one hand that needs rotating as it is a clock) but there's a need to have the hand use rounded or clean square edges so they can't be clipped at an angle. Also - it will run on a smartwatch and it sometimes has issues with rotating elements that go way of the screen so having the hand stay inside the compounds of the screen is ´safer´.

Comment: Create an array of 60 intersection points. To calculate each point you first have to get each line's equation. Then you have to determine which of the bounding box lines it should intersect. Having the 2 lines, you can calculate the intersection point. Store these intersection points in the array and you then can easily draw the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the length you can the following function:

```
// angle: 0-360. 0 = 12 o'clock, 90 = 3 o'clock, ...
// top: the distance of the center to the top side
// right: the distance of the center to the right side
// bottom: the distance of the center to the bottom side
// left: the distance of the center to the left side

function getLength(angle, top, right, bottom, left) {
    var sideToCompare1;
    var sideToCompare2;

    if (angle >= 0 && angle < 90) {
        sideToCompare1 = top;
        sideToCompare2 = right;
    }
    else if (angle >= 90 && angle < 180) {
        sideToCompare1 = right;
        sideToCompare2 = bottom;
        angle -= 90;
    }
    else if (angle >= 180 && angle < 270) {
        sideToCompare1 = bottom;
        sideToCompare2 = left;
        angle -= 180;
    }
    else {
        sideToCompare1 = left;
        sideToCompare2 = top;
        angle -= 270;
    }

    // change to radian
    angle = angle / 180 * Math.PI;

    return Math.min(sideToCompare1 / Math.cos(angle),
                    sideToCompare2 / Math.sin(angle)); //Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - angle)
}
```

The idea in the function is to take the minimum distance to the vertical or the horizontal side that the clock hand would cross.

By rotation the calculation is the same for the four quadrants. That is what happens in the `if`.

Note `cos(90-a) = sin(a)`. That is used to simplify the distance to the second side of each quadrant.

If you want a padding to border of the box, you can either consider the padding perpendicular to box side or in the direction of the hand. In the first case you simply reduce the input parameters by the desired padding. In the second case simply substract the padding from the result of that function.

Comment: Just tried it and it's exactly what I was looking for. I had a vague idea about splitting the rectangle into four quadrants but couldn't figure out how to actually do it. Thank you very much! Apparently I don't have enough reputation to mark it as useful but it most certainly is.

Answer (score 1):

As @VincentChinner said, you can always (literally) hide the complexity.

```js
Math.random.between = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

const createWeb = (el) => {
  const clock = {
    $canvas: el,
    logicalCenter: [Math.random.between(100, 400), Math.random.between(100, 400)],
    segments: 12,
  };
  clock.segmentSize = (Math.PI * 2) / clock.segments;
  clock.$canvas.width = 500;
  clock.$canvas.height = 500;
  clock.ctx = clock.$canvas.getContext('2d');
  clock.ctx.strokeStyle = 'orangered';
  clock.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  clock.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

  const draw = {
    arm: (atSegment) => {
      atSegment = atSegment % clock.segments;
      const degree = atSegment * clock.segmentSize;
      const handLength = clock.$canvas.width * 2;
      const [x, y] = [Math.cos(degree) * handLength, Math.sin(degree) * handLength];

      clock.ctx.beginPath();
      clock.ctx.moveTo(...clock.logicalCenter);
      clock.ctx.lineTo(x + clock.logicalCenter[0], y + clock.logicalCenter[1]);
      clock.ctx.stroke();
    },
    center: (radius) => {
      clock.ctx.beginPath();
      clock.ctx.arc(...clock.logicalCenter, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      clock.ctx.stroke();
    },
    border: (thickness) => {
      const [w, h] = [clock.$canvas.width, clock.$canvas.height];
      clock.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, thickness, h);
      clock.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, thickness);
      clock.ctx.fillRect(0, h - thickness, w, thickness);
      clock.ctx.fillRect(w - thickness, 0, thickness, h);
    }
  };

  draw.center(10);
  Array(clock.segments).fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => i)
    .forEach(draw.arm);
  draw.border(20);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.clock').forEach(createWeb);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px orangered solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="clock"></canvas>
<canvas class="clock"></canvas>
<canvas class="clock"></canvas>
```